# Pandas: calculate weighted average by row using a dataframe and a series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I was trying to make a weighed average and I came across a doubt:

### Problem

I wanted to create a new column named answer that calculates the result between each line and a list of weighted values named in this case as `month`. If I use `df.mean()` I would get a simple average by month and that is not what I want. The idea is to give more importance to the end of the year and less importance to the demand in the begging of the year. So that's why I would like to use weighted average calculation.

In **excel** I would use the formula bellow. I'm having troubles to convert this calculation to pandas data frame.

`=SUMPRODUCT( demands[@[1]:[12]] ; month )/SUM(month)`

I couldn't find a solution to this problem and I really appreciate help with this subject.

Thank you in advance.

Here's a dummy dataframe that serves as an example:

### Example Code

```
demand = pd.DataFrame({'1': [360, 40, 100, 20, 55],
                       '2': [500, 180, 450, 60, 50],
                       '3': [64, 30, 60, 10, 0],
                       '4': [50, 40, 30, 60, 50],
                       '5': [40, 24, 45, 34, 60],
                       '6': [30, 34, 65, 80, 78],
                       '7': [56, 45, 34, 90, 58],
                       '8': [32, 12, 45, 55, 66],
                       '9': [32, 56, 89, 67, 56],
                       '10': [57, 35, 75, 48, 9],
                       '11': [56, 33, 11, 6, 78],
                       '12': [23, 65, 34, 8, 67]
                      })

months = [i for i in range(1,13)]
```

### Visualization of the problem

[image: problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `numpy.average`, specifying `weights`:

```py
demand["result"]=np.average(demand, weights=months, axis=1)
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.average.html

Outputs:

```py
     1    2   3   4   5   6  ...   8   9  10  11  12     result
0  360  500  64  50  40  30  ...  32  32  57  56  23  58.076923
1   40  180  30  40  24  34  ...  12  56  35  33  65  43.358974
2  100  450  60  30  45  65  ...  45  89  75  11  34  58.884615
3   20   60  10  60  34  80  ...  55  67  48   6   8  43.269231
4   55   50   0  50  60  78  ...  66  56   9  78  67  55.294872
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by the following:

```
demand['result'] = (demand * months).sum(axis=1)/sum(months)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```py
den = np.sum(a)
demand['average']=demand['1'].mul(1/den).add(demand['2'].mul(2/den)).add(demand['3'].mul(3/den)).add(demand['4'].mul(4/den)).add(demand['5'].mul(5/den)).add(demand['6'].mul(6/den)).add(demand['7'].mul(7/den)).add(demand['8'].mul(8/den)).add(demand['9'].mul(9/den)).add(demand['10'].mul(10/den)).add(demand['11'].mul(11/den)).add(demand['12'].mul(12/den))
```

The Output:

```py
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  average
0   360 500 64  50  40  30  56  32  32  57  56  23  58.076923
1   40  180 30  40  24  34  45  12  56  35  33  65  43.358974
2   100 450 60  30  45  65  34  45  89  75  11  34  58.884615
3   20  60  10  60  34  80  90  55  67  48  6   8   43.269231
4   55  50  0   50  60  78  58  66  56  9   78  67  55.294872
```